# Azure Logic Apps - HTTP communication between microservices

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-logic-apps

Are Logic Apps considered microservices? If so, is making HTTP API calls from Logic Apps, whether it's using HTTP/Function/APIM connectors, not a violation of direct HTTP communication between microservices?

> If possible, never depend on synchronous communication (request/response) between multiple microservices, not even for queries. The goal of each microservice is to be autonomous and available to the client consumer, even if the other services that are part of the end-to-end application are down or unhealthy. If you think you need to make a call from one microservice to other microservices (like performing an HTTP request for a data query) in order to be able to provide a response to a client application, you have an architecture that will not be resilient when some microservices fail.
>
> Moreover, having HTTP dependencies between microservices, like when creating long request/response cycles with HTTP request chains, as shown in the first part of the Figure 4-15, not only makes your microservices not autonomous but also their performance is impacted as soon as one of the services in that chain is not performing well.
>
> Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/architect-microservice-container-applications/communication-in-microservice-architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Logic Apps are primarily Http based services.  Whether or not it's 'micro' really doesn't matter because 'micro' is too abstract to have any real meaning.  It was a useful marketing term at one point but it's tour on the tech fashion runway has ended.  So, don't even think about that. ;)

What the authors are trying to express is that you should **avoid chaining dependencies** in an app's architecture.  A waits for B which waits for C which waits for D which waits for E, etc...  That's the first line in the graphic.

Instead, Basket can check Catalog on it's own, then call Ordering, while Inventory is checked in the background.  You only one level deep instead of 4.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like we can think of the LA as an API gateway that may make many subsequent API calls and aggregate the results. What about nested logic apps then?

Comment: You can compost Logic Apps, Functions, API Apps, etc in any way you want, there's nothing stopping you.  Nested Logic Apps?  Sure, knock yourself out, but don't go crazy.  Try to keep things as simple as necessary.  I've seen too many crap apps that because the designers were fixated on some 'best practice' or trendy pattern.

Comment: Yes, I want to avoid crap apps as much as possible. ;) Thanks.